# Resizeable div, didn't resize when the content changes

Tags: html, dynamic, resize

I have a div with button in it and resize option. Initially I resized the div and clicked on the button, this button click dynamically populates the content below the button. This div retains the height that I resized and is not getting resize according to the content.

```
 <div id="re">
   <input type="button" value="get" onClick="getdata()"/>
 </div>

 <script>
    $(function(){
     $("#re").resizeable({ 
      handles:'e,w',
      maxWidth:500,
      minWidth:200
    })
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Please share more details in terms of code snippet to check this.

Comment: Charan updated the post please let me know what i need to change